# Hosting HTML page locally in Android Device

Tags: android, localhost, android-webview

I am developing an android app. In that I have used webview to open the html page.
But some of the features on my HTML page would work only if I access the page through server.
How can I host the HTML page locally on my Android device?

For better Idea: 
Example: On PC, I have hosted the html page locally using Apache Tomcat Server.
So to load this HTML page, I have two options
1. Directly double clicking the HTML and opening in browser.
2. Using URL: `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp`

The first option is basic and some of features are not supported.
In second approach, all the features work as expected.

Is there any app/sdk/ open source which I can use to locally host the HTML page?``

Comment: post code that you have try :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/folderName/index.html");
webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/MyWebApp");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for code. But I have already used this code for loading the HTML. I want to load this page as through web-server.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Will check that too. Just out of curiosity wanted to know that the index.html file needs to be saved to some other folder or it it should be placed in Assets folder only?

Comment: hey its load image from your local host of your Host PC not from asset folder

Comment: Let me know from where you want to load your HTML file

Comment: So in that case, if I make a apk of this project and install in my phone, the app wont work! Since the HTML file it is trying to access on 10.0.2.2:8080 will be on my PC. Just a doubt.

Comment: Currently my index.html file is in below path: file:///android_asset/folderName/index.html
I have written same code as suggested by you previously. But it does not serve all of my requirements. The way we host the html pages through Apache Servers in PC, I want to host the HTML page in android. So that the device itself acts as hosting device and the web-view will access the hosted page.

Comment: i think what you want that not possible you have to do manually

Answer (score 0):

Put your file to assets folder and write this

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");

Comment: This code simply loads the html page and does not run on server. I want to render the HTML page through web-server.